# Moisture leaking out of chip in floor tile

Tags: tile, moisture, damage

I dropped something heavy and mildly pointed onto the bathroom floor.

The Bathroom is tiled with ~30cm square black "slate like" tiles, but where I dropped this thing, the surface has been badly (2-3 cm radius, ?1-2mm deep?) chipped, and underneath the tile is pale brown.

Since I chipped it, there has been moisture welling up, through the chip. Initially I assumed it was just from the object dropped (it was wet), but the chip is still wet, and if I pat it thoroughly dry with toilet roll, then it 'spontaneously' becomes wet enough to mark a mark on toilet roll again, in <10 seconds.

The rest of the chipped tile, the other tiles, and the grout between the tiles all seem fine; no darkness, claminess, or any other sign of dampness.

**What have I done, and what do I need to do now?**

I know nothing about the tiles in question and don't (to my knowledge) have any spares.

Comment: Can you provide a picture and give us an idea of how far away it is from water sources such as the shower, toilet, and sink?

Comment: Yep, in a bathroom I would suspect a leaky shower or a leaky toilet gasket.  You need to figure out the source of the water and fix the leak.

Comment: If this in a basement you need a sump. Or just grout it and forget about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get a dehumidifier running in there and see if you can dry it out, you’ll have to stop using the bathroom (if you can) and it might take a while (possibly days)  Once it’s completely dry try using one fixture at a time and see if you can isolate the cause.  The other posts have given you some good advice and you might end up paying someone to rip up that tile etc, but if you’re desperate to avoid doing that you might be able to avoid it and the dehumidifier will help prevent/slow down any mould growth that might be happening anyway.

Comment: +1, this question calls for an alternative to "tear it all up", since that simply won't be possible for everyone faced with this situation.

Comment: This is what we're going with, for the moment. Thanks. We've stopped using the shower, but alas this is the only loo, so can't avoid that.

Comment: OP beware, it may take very _very_ long time to dry the moisture with an air dehumidifier, and when done, it may take a long time again for the water to seep to the crack, invalidating any trials with one fixture at a time. Something similar happened at the building I live in, it took some tile removal, specialized vacuum dryers, $3,000 electricity bill and eight weeks to get the structure sufficiently dry (there was about 8 thousand liters of water in the structure _before_ water even started to show itself above the tile line). Insurance covered all costs in this particular case.

Comment: These can be really hard situations and Pavels story sounds like a true life horror story, but I hope yours doesn’t turn into that.  Are you able to see the floor underneath?  Could you potentially cut some holes in the ceiling below to try and see where the leak is?  Repairing dry wall is usually the better option but I realize it might not be possible.

Comment: For the water to get so saturated through the tiles to squeeze water out when chipped... logically I know that's possible, but I don't even know how long a tile needs to be sitting in water before it'll soak right through and can "leak" water from the top...

Comment: @Steve +1 for alternative access --- ventilation will speed up drying process enormously (if possible!), so has advantages beyond visual inspection. There's a small chance you can color toilet water sufficiently (with these blue cleaning blocks in the cistern) to see if the colour spreads; but a leak in a random tube is quite likely --- it's a connection that leaks more likely than a piercing. I had a leak at downstairs entrance, thought from awning; by chance traced to a badly-connected upstairs toilet (inflow connector boxed in) when that got replaced.

Comment: What I tried to say with colored water is that if flow is sufficiently high, you can sometimes trace the cause upstream with an innocent die (say, a red / blue / yellow food color), a bit like a contrast fluid for medical imaging.   If you have a way to disconnect sections & feed coloured water you're in! But that's a bit unlikely --- e.g. put 'cistern' cleaning blocks in the main toilet bowl, that can only show up if the syphon leaks.

Answer (score 44):

I think your cracking the floor is a blessing in disguise.  Clearly there is water under the tile that needs to be dealt with.

I'd start by checking the obvious things like the toilet seal and the bathtub and/or shower drains.

But ultimately you're going to want to pull that tile up, dry it out thoroughly, replace any water-damaged materials, and replace the flooring.  There is no way it will dry out on its own at this point.

Comment: balls. :( This was not the answer I wanted to hear :_(  (Thanks for teling me though)

Comment: @Brondahl, do you have any in-floor heating system that could be leaking?

Comment: Nope. But the shower (2 feet away) has been leaking into the wall it's attached to.
The heavy object I dropped was the shower screen (which shattered on impact. Sigh), which I was removing in order to give access to the wall tiles whose grout had failed, thus causing the leak into the wall.

Comment: Is is plausible that that leak into the wall could be extending down across the floor? (and hence that once the shower is no longer leaking into the wall, the floor won't have an issue?)

Comment: Agree with your assessment though the probability of leaking plumbing behind the shower wall is as likely, especially in an older bathroom.

Comment: FYI, the tiler who is dealing with the shower (whom I have used repeatedly, and trust) has confirmed that this is almost certainly the "proper" way to deal with this. (But also acknowledges that this solution is more expensive that is appropriate for us).

Comment: You can replace single tiles, you could (fix the cause of the leak then), dry the room out with a carpet fan for several days, and replace the single tile, see if it's enough... :)

Comment: I'd be very wary of any 'patch it up' approaches. At least part of the structure beneath the tiles must be absolutely saturated for the water pressure to be causing the phenomenon you describe. If the floor of the bathroom is in any way structural to the house, ie wooden beams that are holding your house together then you need to address it. Do you have any insurance that might help?

Answer (score 10):

It’s highly unlikely that “failed” grout would create the refill rate of wet flooring you describe. Most shower failures are generated by leaky or failing plumbing in the wall, behind the tile.

I have often seen the water damage extend to the framing, which necessitates cutting out and replacing that portion of framing. Your wet floor problem needs to be addressed ASAP.

Turn off the water to the shower and/or bathroom plumbing  Pull up all damaged tiles and as mentioned, check toilet plumbing and seals. Allow all wet areas to dry out. The wet source must be identified and repaired or risk of much great damage can occur.

This is probably a job for a professional who does bathroom remodeling. I did it for 12 years.

Answer (score 10):

**Call a plumber immediately!**
This is uncomfortably close to my recent experiences..

My kitchen floor had a damaged tile (similar story, something got dropped on it) and water was welling up from under it when it was stepped on.

We thought it might have been absorbed by water seeping into the damaged area, so it wasn't a huge issue, it would dry out, then it would become wet again inexplicably and we assumed water was just being spilled on it.

Then my neighbour in the flat below let us know that there was water coming through their kitchen ceiling (small amounts, but a steady dripping)

After some investigation we found that there was a slow drip from the new kitchen faucet that we'd had installed recently.
That water was flowing into a hole in the wall behind and under the kitchen sink, straight down into the neighbour's ceiling, soaking into the lining under the tiles as it went.

I got it fixed, the water stopped. As far as I know, problem solved with no permanent damage to the flat below.
We were lucky to catch it relatively quickly because the tile was damaged.

At any rate. Just a guess, one of your pipes is leaking and it's getting under your bathroom floor-tiles.
Call the plumber, be prepared to spend lots on fixing it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.